# Wordpress email confirmation

Tags: email, email-confirmation

My boss wants me to make some sort of email order confirmation. It has to be like this:

A private page in which only people who have password can access.On this page, there is 6 input boxes, where you can write the Name, Address, Number, Price, a sort of remember if something was talked about in the meeting "like special notices", and a email for the customer it the has to send out a email there says something like:

Hello 

"Then a automatic message"
Thanks you for the meeting here is the contract as agreed upon the price is 
etc and ofc the info of the customer, 
and then our info at the bottom.

There has to be logo on top as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress Confirmation link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845299/wordpress-confirmation-link)

Comment: The link above is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin does exactly what you need - [**Pie Register**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/)

Enhance default Registration form, Custom logo, Password field, Invitation codes, Paypal, Captcha validation, Email verification, user moderation &amp

From [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/) Plugin Directory:

Then try this

**[Contact-form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)**

or

[**Contact Form**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-plugin/)

Comment: Hmmm isint this more, for register? i dont see how this is what i need :)

Comment: Try my two plugins in my updated answer .. They are pretty simple to configure ..

Comment: Thank you contact-form 7 seem to be just what i need! :) Thank you very much